# SQL Server : storing date and time in separate columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, time, default-value

I am using SQL Server 2008 :

1. I want to keep date and time separated
2. I want both of them to have default value like NOW() when record is created
3. How can I control format of date and time

So far I have this code :

```
 CREATE TABLE [Table1]
 (
    [RECORD_ID] int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [INPUT_ID] int NOT NULL,
    [DATE] date DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    [TIME] time(7) DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    PRIMARY KEY ([RECORD_ID])
 )
```

I just don't know how to set time condensed data type to `time(0)`. Is rest of my code ok, or there is a better approach ?

Comment: Have you tried your code? Besides the formatting, I think it will work fine. To format output, there are functions you can use at the output (SELECT queries, reporting) to control it.

Comment: Yes the code is tested, I even tried to replace time(7) with time(0). I don't control the output I am just creating tables as others want :) In MS SQl Server Mng Studio I can set Condensed Data Type to "time(0)" - I would like to do that when creating table.

Comment: If you want to store the time with second only accuracy, use `time(0)` (instead of `(7)` in the CREATE table.) If you want it stored with full accuracy (7) but occasionally show only the seconds, you can use `SELECT CAST([time] AS time(0)) AS time_displayed` in your queries.

Comment: Now I tried time(0) again and it worked. I am bit confused. Probably my mistake. Thank you !